# Read-only Run elements in a WPF RichTextBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, richtextbox, .net-3.5

I may be completely imagining this, but I could have sworn there was a way to make individual Run (or Parapgraph) elements in a RichTextBox read-only. I also could have sworn I tried a method for doing this out myself a few weeks ago and was satisfied with the results - I vaguely remember it looked something like this:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox"
             AcceptsTab="True"
             AcceptsReturn="True"
             FontFamily="Courier New"
             FontSize="14">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run IsReadOnly="True">I wish this was read-only!</Run>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Now, a few weeks later, I go to try to make Run elements read-only in a RichTextBox only to find it doesn't seem to be possible.

[This post on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/329079fc-8555-4192-b90e-6fccd43bf28a) seems to confirm that.

Did I completely imagine this? Or is there a way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, I've come up with a solution that works for my case - but may not work for everyone who wants something like this. It's messy, but it does the job.

I'm not going to accept my own answer for a few days, just in case someone else has a better way of accomplishing this.

Here we go, first, the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1"
        Height="500"
        Width="600">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <RichTextBox x:Name="rtb"
                     FontFamily="Courier New"
                     FontSize="14"
                     PreviewKeyDown="rtb_PreviewKeyDown">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <InlineUIContainer Unloaded="InlineUIContainer_Unloaded">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="14">This line of text is not editable.</TextBlock>
                    </InlineUIContainer>
                    <Run Foreground="Blue">But this is editable.</Run>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InlineUIContainer_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as InlineUIContainer).Unloaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(InlineUIContainer_Unloaded);

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Courier New");
            tb.FontSize = 14;
            tb.Text = "This line of text is not editable.";

            TextPointer tp = rtb.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            InlineUIContainer iuic = new InlineUIContainer(tb, tp);
            iuic.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(InlineUIContainer_Unloaded);
        }

        private void rtb_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                var newPointer = rtb.Selection.Start.InsertLineBreak();
                rtb.Selection.Select(newPointer, newPointer);

                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My solution relies on the fact that when an `InlineUIContainer` is removed from the UI, it's `Unloaded()` method is called. At that point, I simply reinsert the deleted `InlineUIContainer` at the current caret position.

As with any hack, there are a bunch of disadvantages. The disadvantages I'm finding are the following:

- The text I want to be read-only needs to be wrapped in a `InlineUIContainer`. That is a little limiting for this solution.
- I have to capture the 'Enter' key and insert line breaks manually, otherwise, `InlineUIContainer.Unloaded()` keeps firing everytime the Enter key is pressed. Not fun, but it works for my case.

It's not a great solution, but I think it will work for me. Like I said, I'm not going to mark this as an answer to my own question yet - hopefully someone else will have a better way of doing this.

Comment: Very interesting it will help me add "widgets" if you will into the text editor. I'm making a very nice windows like Wiki editor. So for adding images, categories, and keywords I'm using small objects that decorate the rich text object. I wish the editor was a little more like the visual studio editor. This way I could add "Adornments" but... this definitively helped me! Thanks.

Comment: Glad it could help - be warned, though - I vaguely remember it being possible to delete read-only text with the backspace key. I'm not sure after all of this time, but I'd test it thoroughly to ensure the widgets remain read-only.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by handling two event: 1) OnMouseDown 2) OnPreviewKeyDown

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
public class MultiPartTextBox : TextBox
{
    private string _prefix;
    private string _content;

    public string Prefix
    {
        get { return _prefix; }
        set { _prefix = value;
        Text = _prefix;
        }
    }

    public string Content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set { 
            _content = value;
            Text = _prefix + _content;
        }
    }

    public MultiPartTextBox() { _prefix = string.Empty; }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        this.SelectionStart = _prefix.Length;
        this.SelectionLength = 0;
    }

    //tab In
    protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectionStart = _prefix.Length;
        this.SelectionLength = 0;
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Back 
            || e.Key == Key.Delete
            || e.Key==Key.Left)
        {
            if (CaretIndex <= _prefix.Length)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    }
  }
  }
```

IN Xaml we have to handle it in following way:

```
   xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"

       <uc:MultiPartTextBox Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Margin="80,94,0,0" x:Name="multiPartTxt1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Width="224" Prefix="NON-EDITABLE" CaretIndex="4" >            
       </uc:MultiPartTextBox>
```

Comment: You forgot about finger touches.