# How to have a portion of WPF RichTextBox as read-only and another portion as read-write?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox

On RichTextBox users will be typing query and the result must be appended to the same RichTextBox(the result must be read-only). Again user must have the option to type the second query.

Is there a way we can do it using single RichTextBox? It needs to be single RichTextBox so that user can scroll across the quires and results.

Comment: I'm not really into wpf but maxbe you could try building a workarround for this one. I guess there's something like a current selection index. If it's im the range that wont be allowed to edit just set the `ReadOnly` property to true

Comment: you can use multibinding.

Comment: Here is one option - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1084495/5311735