# How to make TextBlock inside of Rich Text Box Non-removable?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

```cs
private void AddVCard()
        {
            FlowDocument flowDocument = rich.Document;
            Paragraph dp = new Paragraph(); 
            Run fnRun = new Run() {Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black };
            Run companyRun = new Run() {Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black };
            Run telRun = new Run() {Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black };
            Run emailRun = new Run() { Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black };
            Run adrRun = new Run() {Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black };
            
            InlineUIContainer fnTb = new InlineUIContainer(new TextBlock() {  Tag = "fn", Text = "First Name:", Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green });
            InlineUIContainer ctbh = new InlineUIContainer(new TextBlock() {  Tag = "company", Text = "Company:", Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green });
            InlineUIContainer teltb = new InlineUIContainer(new TextBlock() { Tag = "tel", Text = "Phone/Tel No:", Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green });
            InlineUIContainer emailtb = new InlineUIContainer(new TextBlock() {  Tag = "email", Text = "Email:", Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green });
            InlineUIContainer adrtb = new InlineUIContainer(new TextBlock() {  Tag = "adr", Text = "Address:", Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green });
            fnTb.Unloaded += InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_1;
            ctbh.Unloaded += InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_2;
            teltb.Unloaded += InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_3;
            emailtb.Unloaded += InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_4;
            adrtb.Unloaded += InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_5;
            dp.Inlines.Add(fnTb);
            //np.Inlines.Add(fnTb);

            dp.Inlines.Add(fnRun);
            dp.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

            dp.Inlines.Add(ctbh);
            //np.Inlines.Add(ctbh);

            dp.Inlines.Add(companyRun);
            dp.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

            dp.Inlines.Add(teltb);
            //np.Inlines.Add(teltb);

            dp.Inlines.Add(telRun);
            dp.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

            dp.Inlines.Add(emailtb);
            //np.Inlines.Add(emailtb);

            dp.Inlines.Add(emailRun);
            dp.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

            dp.Inlines.Add(adrtb);
            //np.Inlines.Add(adrtb);

            dp.Inlines.Add(adrRun);

            vcardRuns["fn"] = fnRun;
            vcardRuns["company"] = companyRun;
            vcardRuns["tel"] = telRun;
            vcardRuns["email"] = emailRun;
            vcardRuns["adr"] = adrRun;

            // Get the FlowDocument of the RichTextBox
            

            // Add the dynamicParagraph to the Blocks collection
            flowDocument.Blocks.Add(dp);
        }

        private void InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as InlineUIContainer).Unloaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_1);

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = "Full Name:";
            tb.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green; 

            TextPointer tp = rich.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            //rich.CaretPosition = rich.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(tb.Text.Length+1);
            InlineUIContainer iuic = new InlineUIContainer(tb, tp);
            iuic.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_1);
        }

        private void InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as InlineUIContainer).Unloaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_2);

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = "Company:";
            tb.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;

            TextPointer tp = rich.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            //rich.CaretPosition = rich.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(tb.Text.Length+1);
            InlineUIContainer iuic = new InlineUIContainer(tb, tp);
            iuic.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_2);
        }

        private void InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as InlineUIContainer).Unloaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_3);

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = "Phone/Tel:";
            tb.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;

            TextPointer tp = rich.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            //rich.CaretPosition = rich.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(tb.Text.Length+1);
            InlineUIContainer iuic = new InlineUIContainer(tb, tp);
            iuic.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_3);
        }

        private void InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as InlineUIContainer).Unloaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_4);

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = "Email:";
            tb.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;

            TextPointer tp = rich.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            //rich.CaretPosition = rich.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(tb.Text.Length+1);
            InlineUIContainer iuic = new InlineUIContainer(tb, tp);
            iuic.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_4);
        }

        private void InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as InlineUIContainer).Unloaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_5);

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = "Address:";
            tb.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;

            TextPointer tp = rich.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            //rich.CaretPosition = rich.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(tb.Text.Length+1);
            InlineUIContainer iuic = new InlineUIContainer(tb, tp);
            iuic.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(InlineUIContainer_Unloaded_5);
        }
}
```

(code updated)
I have the following code in which im adding text blocks to dynamic paragraph inlines but the user is able to entirely remove the textblocks just like any other text.

I dont want the user to remove the TextBlock and i want to stay fixed just there.

**Update**: I tried following [Read-only run element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084495/read-only-run-elements-in-a-wpf-richtextbox) post but Im unable to move the caret to the corresponding run and I think if this is done properly then the issue should most likely be resolved.

Comment: Does [Read-only Run elements in a WPF RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1084495) answer your question?

Comment: `TextBlock` has an `IsEnabled` property. I wonder whether setting it to `false` would freeze it?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Nope it doesn't do anything

Comment: @dbc It actually works but when i type, the editable Runs values are not set im not understanding where i have to place the caret after replacing the text blocks after it gets unloaded in the event so that its placed in the right Run

Comment: @Rushaan - then I'd suggest you [edit] your question and update it with the code you adapted from [Read-only Run elements in a WPF RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1084495) that shows what you tried and how it isn't quite working -- i.e. an updated [mcve].

Comment: What you want is not possible out of the box. You must agree that this would provide an extremely weird user experience. The cursor would either be blocked or weirdly jump across the document. Also content that was deleted that suddenly reappears is a weird concept too. You may consider using adoners to overlay the document content. This should be a more graceful solution. It's also more lightweight than modifying the heavy FlowDocument.